# php while loop error db

Tags: php, echo

```
function DisplayPoints()
    {   

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "grame2_admin", "password") ;
    if (!$con) {
    die("Can not connected: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("grame2_webpage",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT points FROM tablename WHERE username = $username";
    $myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
```

> It echo out info, that there is error in line 164, LINE ABOVE THIS.

```
    echo $record['points'] ;

    }
    mysql_close($con);

}
```

> the main idea is to echo out INT from specific user in webpage. Please help! :)

Comment: IF you get an error you should post it here so that other user know what error you get and can help you

Comment: Thanks it doesnt show error now, but it doesnt show INT . I want to see it, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @EmilMorris Is it a complete code for that function? Where `$username` variable is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$sql = "SELECT points FROM tablename WHERE username = $username";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT points FROM tablename WHERE username = '$username'";
                                                      ^         ^
```

*On a side note use prepared statements with either mysqli or PDO. mysql extension is deprecated and is no longer supported.*

**UPDATE** The other problem is that your `$username` variable is not initialized. You probably need to pass it to your function as a parameter

```
function DisplayPoints($username) 
{
    ...
}
```

And when you call your function pass a value

```
DisplayPoints('user1');
```

or

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
// here should go code to validate and sanitize $username
DisplayPoints($username);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code that you posted. Did you try to execute your query directly in mysql?

Comment: forgive, but I did not understand what you mean by that

Comment: I mean did you try to execute the query `SELECT points FROM tablename WHERE username = '<substitute with the value from $username'` using phpmyadmin or mysql command line utility or any other client tool for mysql? You may not have a record with a username that is assigned to $username variable. Or $username variable can contain wrong value or contain no value.

Comment: No I havent. Where i need to assign it- somewhere in phpmyamdin or in function DisplayPoints() code? and what i have to do to assign it? Mabe there is some tutorial in web that you know?

Comment: HOLLLY SH*T! YOU ARE THE BEST, IT WORKED. BIG, BIG THANKS BRO, RESPECT. :) :) :)